# Online Store in Cheyenne, Wyoming Accepting Bitcoin for Payment

Tags: aml, know-your-customer

Can an online store located in Cheyenne, Wyoming accept bitcoin as payment for goods from customers in either Wyoming, or other states or countries, without collecting every customers Social Security Number, or other KYC and AML type identifying information, without the possibility of being prosecuted for money laundering by either Wyoming or the US Federal Government?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be answered by a lawyer familiar with that jurisdiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For absolute clarity, you should consult the appropriate lawyer / tax professional in your jurisdiction.

However, in general, accepting bitcoin for payment should be no different than accepting any other form of payment. Think of it like accepting a foreign currency, and apply the appropriate accounting practices. There are even services out there which allow you to accept payment from customers in bitcoin, but will then pay you out in your local currency.

KYC/AML type stuff usually applies to businesses that are *money transmitters*, trading one form of currency for another. But as I mentioned above, if you are truly worried, then you shouldn't take the advice of a stranger on the internet, you should hire the appropriate professional to advise you on the matter.